# Remove user's permissions (django)

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-permissions

I have an issue with removing permissions to users in view or even in the shell. Let me explain my problem:

I did those tests in the shell:

```
org = Organisateur.objects.get(user__username__contains="ghj") 
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Tournoi)
```

Tournoi is the name of a model

```
permission_ecriture = 'ecriture_Palaiseau'
permission = Permission.objects.get(content_type=content_type, codename=permission_ecriture)
org.user.user_permissions.remove(permission)`
```

but when I write:

```
org.user.has_perm('inscription.ecriture_Palaiseau')`
```

it returns True

but when I rewrite:

```
org = Organisateur.objects.get(user__username__contains="ghj")
org.user.has_perm('inscription.ecriture_Palaiseau')`
```

it returns False

It is really weird. Why does it works like this?

In my views, it seems that the permissions are not removed even if I do write:

```
org = Organisateur.objects.get(user__username__contains="ghj")
```

(after removing the permission, the user still has it)

What I want to do is to remove a permission from an user and add another permission to the same user immediately after.
But each time I do that, the user still has the "removed permission"......

Thank you very much

I look forward to hearing from you all soon.

Answer (score 9):

This behavior is expected because permissions are cached. From the Django docs:

> **[Permission caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching)**
>
> The ModelBackend caches permissions on the User object after the first time they need to be fetched for a permissions check. This is typically fine for the request-response cycle since permissions are not typically checked immediately after they are added (in the admin, for example). If you are adding permissions and checking them immediately afterward, in a test or view for example, the easiest solution is to re-fetch the User from the database.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is almost right, you just have forgotten to save your `user object` at the end!

use `user.save()`